# Language is not changing after hosting at iis

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

In my application the user can change the language to English, French,  or Spanish.

Below is the method that gets called when the user changes culture:

```
public ActionResult ChangeCulture(string lang, string returnUrl)
{
    if (Request.Cookies["Culture"] != null) {
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Culture"];
        cookie.Values["Language"] = lang;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;
        Response.SetCookie(cookie);
    } else {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Culture");
        cookie.Values["Language"] = lang;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
}
```

This code is working fine, when we run from VS.

But if we host the same code on IIS and then try to change the language, it's not working.

I am setting the default language to "English" in `Global.asax`.
If we try to change the language, it's setting to english only.